# How to hide the redundant "Month Week Day" tabs above the fullcalendar

Tags: tabs, hide, fullcalendar

I've spent hours researching this so have to ask:  How do I hide the redundant tabs at the top of my fullcalendar in Drupal.  I've looked at the javascript and Drupal's view for fullcalendars and can't see how to remove it.  I'm trying to hide the first "MONTH WEEK DAY" tabs that are above the view of the calendar, as shown in the image below, not the lower tabs:

[image]

Comment: If all else fails, why not just hide them with some css? Or even just modify the DOM? It's messy, but...

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it out:  I was clicking on an OLD link from the old calendar that was showing in my navigation and once I deleted that and show other views it works great.   Before that I was tempted to hide with CSS but the only identifying elements were UL's with classes of "primary" and "tags" and I didn't want to hide that and throw out some babies with the bath water...  
Thanks though...